# Is Empty selection in an NSTableView with Source List Highlighting not allowed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I feel like I may be missing something obvious here, but if I have an NSTableView with it's Highlight set to Source List and with Empty selection enabled, I don't seem to be able to click on a blank row in the table to clear the selection.

Changing the Highlight to regular fixes the problem, but of course doesn't draw in the manner I'd like.

The table has no bindings and uses a custom data source. Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I've ended up adding the following to my NSTableView subclass:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    if ( [self allowsEmptySelection] && [self selectionHighlightStyle] == NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList )
    {
        NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:[self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil]];
        if ( row == -1 )
        {
            [self deselectAll:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use target actions to accomplish this. During initialization do the following:

```
self.tableView.delegate             = self;
self.tableView.dataSource           = self;
self.tableView.target               = self;
self.tableView.action               = @selector(singleClickAction:);
self.tableView.allowsEmptySelection = YES;
```

Then add a method to your class:

```
- (void)singleClickAction:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger clickedRow = [sender clickedRow];
    if (clickedRow < 0) {
        [self.tableView deselectAll:self];
    }
}
```